# How can I see progress of all Features with a Progress bar

Tags: progress-bar, status, feature-scaling

On Azure DevOps board, progress bars are available only at the user story level, but I want to see the progress at higher levels.
Do you have a suggestion?

I didn't find a way to reflect the progress of features